# LC-circuit with AC-supply - Current flowing through the coil

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

> A parallel LC-circuit is connected to an AC-supply as in the figure below.
>
> [image]
>
> $I_{tot}(t)=I_0sin(\omega t+\phi)$, $\phi$ is the phase angle between $V_{tot}(t)$ and $I_{tot}(t)$
>
> a) Determine $\phi$.
>
> b) What current $I_L(t)$(Amplitude and phase) runs through the coil **L**?
>
> Use the following information: $R=10 \Omega, ~C=30\mu F,~L=10^{-3}H,~I_0=2A,~\omega =300\frac{1}{s}$

I was never good with LC-circuits, which is why I picked out this one out of my textbook.

How do I approach this type of exercise?

I was thinking that since it's an LC-circuit then because of Lenz's law the phase is $\phi =90°$? Is that also the case here? And the resistor $R$ kind of bugs me in the circuit. Does it have any influence on the current or the phase?

How do I get the amplitude and phase in b)? Although I still think that the phase should be $90°$. But what about the amplitude?

I guess part of the current would flow through **R**, right? Meaning the 'amplitude' of the current in **L** is a little less. But how would I get the value of $I_R$? I don't have a value for the voltage **V**.

Sorry for my lack of work here. My knowledge on curcuits in general is really slim.

Comment: You still need to show some work, to get help. Did you try writing an equation to connect the voltage, to the current through complex impedance? Are you familiar with Kirchoff's laws?

Comment: @leastaction 
We didn't discuss impedance in class yet. We did discuss Kirchhoff's law at the beginning of the semester. But as far as I remember you can't apply on an AC-supply only DC?

Comment: Kirchoff's laws apply equally to ac and dc circuits. The engineering way to solve this would be to use the *current divider* rule.

Comment: @ThePhoton I never heard of the current divider rule, I'm in my second semester of physics right now. I also don't know how to apply Kirchoff's laws here.

Comment: Did they not teach you to use google yet?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how we can help you unless you show some attempts to work on this problem yourself. The most I can advise you is to consult books such as (1) Physics by Resnick, Halliday and Krane (volume 2), or (2) Physics for Scientists and Engineers by Giancoli. This is not a difficult problem, but if this is homework, you must first review the theory for it -- which if not covered in class, is certainly covered in these books (and many others). Even if you are interested in the "plug-and-chug" formulae to solve this specific problem, they are given in books.